# Reflection to get default value of parameter

Tags: java, kotlin, reflection

I am trying to use reflection to get all the optional fields in a class and their default values (if any). This is my attempt:

```
fun getOptionalFields(componentType: KClass<out Any>): Map<String, DefaultValueData>  {
    val cons = componentType.primaryConstructor
    val constructorSetup = cons?.parameters
        ?.filterNot { it.isOptional }
        ?.associate { it to getValueForNonOptional(it) } ?: error("Something went wrong when choosing default val")
    val constructorInst = (cons.callBy(constructorSetup)::class as KClass<Any>)

    val conParams = (componentType.primaryConstructor?.parameters ?: emptyList())
        .filter { p -> p.isOptional }
        .associate { p ->
            Pair(p.name ?: "",
                DefaultValueData(
                    p.type,
// the below line crashes
                    constructorInst.memberProperties.first { m -> m.name == p.name }.get(constructorInst)
                )
            )
        }

    return conParams
}
```

The error: **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class**

I am a bit puzzled at what get() wants me to pass if not the instance to get the value from?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just create an instance and check the properties?

Comment: I am not able to redroduce your problem. The line that should cause the problem runs fine with kotlin 1.6.21. Your line to get the `constructorInst` can be reduced to `val constructorInst = componentType`

Comment: @wartoshika the point of using callBy is that we can pass any class to this method and it will be able to instantiate it with its default values. This will allow us to see what are the default values provided inside that class.

Comment: @lukas.j this is part of a large offline process, this method needs to handle almost any class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get the value by providing a KClass instead of the actual instance.

This is a working solution based on your method signature and your code above:

```
data class Test(
    val required: String,
    val optional: Int = 7
)

val componentType = Test::class
val constructorInst = Test("required") // i skipped constructing the class via constructor

val conParams = (componentType.primaryConstructor?.parameters ?: emptyList())
    .filter { p -> p.isOptional }
    .associate { p ->
        Pair(p.name ?: "",
            Pair(
                p.type,
                componentType.memberProperties.first { m -> m.name == p.name }.get(constructorInst)
            )
        )
    }

println(conParams)  // <- OUTPUTS: {optional=(kotlin.Int, 7)}
```

Why have i removed this code?

```
    val constructorSetup = cons?.parameters
        ?.filterNot { it.isOptional }
        ?.associate { it to getValueForNonOptional(it) } ?: error("Something went wrong when choosing default val")
    val constructorInst = (cons.callBy(constructorSetup)::class as KClass<Any>)
```

The resulting object `cons.callBy(constructorSetup)` is unused because calling `::class` on the expression rendered it useless. Additionally it is not required to perform the requested task in your question.

When updating your above code, result will look like

```
fun getOptionalFields(componentType: KClass<out Any>): Map<String, DefaultValueData>  {
    val cons = componentType.primaryConstructor
    val constructorSetup = cons?.parameters
        ?.filterNot { it.isOptional }
        ?.associate { it to getValueForNonOptional(it) } ?: error("Something went wrong when choosing default val")
    val constructorInst = cons.callBy(constructorSetup)  // <- removed ::class and cast

    val conParams = (componentType.primaryConstructor?.parameters ?: emptyList())
        .filter { p -> p.isOptional }
        .associate { p ->
            val value = constructorInst::class.memberProperties.first { m -> m.name == p.name }.get(constructorInst) as KProperty1<out Any, out Any>
            Pair(p.name ?: "",
                DefaultValueData(
                    p.type,
                    value
                )
            )
        }

    return conParams
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, if you take out ::class you will not have access to memberProperties

Comment: you are right, adding it onto the buttom line should work. i have updated my answer

Comment: now I have type mismatch on "constructorInst"...Require "Nothing" Found "Any"

Comment: I see, i have updated my answer again, a cast is required (`as KProperty1<out Any, out Any>`) to get this value because of the wildcard generic on `memberProperties`. memperProperties returns `Collection<KProperty1<T, *>>` and the `*` in the value type position does not allow to access the value. Therefore a cast must be done to access the value.

Comment: Ok, I got it to work. You were on the right idea, but the solution was to have both:
val constructorInst = (cons.callBy(constructorSetup))
val constructorMeta = (constructorInst::class as KClass<Any>)
Then use like this: constructorMeta.memberProperties.first { m -> m.name == p.name }.get(constructorInst)

Comment: Glad we could worked out your problem together :)